# How do I add validation to text area in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper, oracle-apex-20.2, oracle-apex-20.1, oracle-apex21.2

I am feed up with this Oracle APEX application , their is no proper videos or documentation

I have a Text area field and button

On button click I have written a PL/SQL code to send mail

Is their any way I can populate error / success message on screen

If text area is empty does not have any data then display error message on screen as Text area field is empty

**My code :**

```
BEGIN
    if (:textarea1 is not null ) then
           APEX_MAIL.SEND(p_from => 'alice@example.com',
                   p_to   => 'bob@example.com',
                   p_subj => 'Email from Oracle Autonomous Database',
                   p_body => 'Sent using APEX_MAIL');
    else
               --popup error message on my screen -> `textarea` filed cannot be empty 
    end if;   
END;
```

The following package of `ADD_ERROR.ADD_ERROR` does not exist at my end

Answer (score 2):

> If text area is empty does not have any data then display error message on screen

You don't need your own validation for that; just set that item's **Value required** property ON.

---

Additionally, you can even set process' **Server side condition** to

- When button pressed: pick the button you use to send an e-mail
- Type: Item is not null; pick the text area item

---

You commented that it isn't working. Well, it is. If it doesn't for you, then you did something wrong (although, I can't imagine what would that be, regarding the fact that it is just one property you had to set).

So: if I leave the text area empty and push the button, error message is here:

[image]

As of a *video with demonstration*: I don't have any. Google for it, if you desperately need it.

Comment: : Not working ... any video with an demonstration

Comment: It *is working*; see demo in edited answer.